# Is there a way to continuously show Firefox bookmark tags for the active tab?

Tags: firefox, bookmarks, tags

Assume I have a Firefox window with many opened tabs (e.g. 50+). Some of the tabs show bookmarked URLs, of which some have [bookmark tags](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/categorizing-bookmarks-make-them-easy-to-find) assigned.

As I change the active tab, I can see at a glance if it shows a bookmarked URL by looking at the golden star shown in the address bar.

**Problem:** I can't just as easily see the tags assigned to the bookmark shown in the active tab. For that I need to open the Edit This Bookmark window by clicking on the star in the address bar or using a keyboard shortcut. Is there a way to see those tags without performing any additional operations?